# Why don't Lists and Libraries show up in SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services

I have a SharePoint 2010 site that works correctly, and a subsite that does not.  When I open the subsite in SharePoint Designer, the "Lists and Libraries" view says "There are no items to show in this view." even though there are both Lists and Libraries defined for the subsite.

If I visit the `http://site/subsite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc` page it returns an empty document. `http://site/_vti_bin/ListData.svc` returns a valid XML document.

I have Full Control permissions for the subsite, and the Lists and Libraries all show up if I view the "All Files" folder.  I have installed the data services update.

Update: I have also checked the SharePoint Designer settings.  All permissions are selected globally and for the site collection in question.  The top level site in the collection is working correctly; Only the subsite has issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up deleting the broken subsite and creating a new one. The new subsite works correctly.

Answer (score 10):

Having the same problem, I found a way.

First, I knew a list was broken, based on symptoms reported from other answers in this post ([You should also check out this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16000/why-isnt-sharepoint-designer-2010-showing-anything-under-list-and-libraries/74233#74233), as it is quite informative).  For one, alirobe's mentioning that `/_vti_bin/ListData.svc` isn't accessible if a list is broken.

When I went to "All Site Content", every list given there *did* work.

I couldn't discover which list it was that was broken, so in SPD, I went to "All Files" in Sharepoint Designer - which worked, even though many of the other Site Objects in "Navigation" didn't display anything.

I went through every list in "All Files" and used "Preview in Browser" on every one of them.  Finally, I came to one that didn't open!  Instead, it said,

> feature d57f48.... for list template '100' is not installed in this farm...

So I deleted that list and everything began working again just fine in SPD.

There is a [list of features here](http://sharepoint-geek.com/2010/10/08/sharepoint-2007-moss-features/), by the way.

Comment: Great: "I went through every list in "All Files" and used "Preview in Browser" on every one of them". This worked for me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks mate that really worked for me, I had issue with workflow and I wasn't able to create any workflow. Upon clicking on Workflows an then choosing desired list, nothing was happening. Then I follow your steps and went through all items of All Files and finally I realised that I had a problematic list containing PowerView report. I simply deleted that list and life back to normal, cheers mate.

Answer (score 5):

It was probably a problem with one of your lists or list templates. If you have a broken list, then it'll kill the listdata.svc page. See here: http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-designer-2010-listlibrary-there-are-no-items-to-show-in-this-view-listdata-svc-woes

Comment: How can I find the broken list without trying to delete everything one by one and restoring them?

Comment: Checking ULS logs help, as they list, as it mentions the troubled feature id: `Feature '102e3c2b-02a2-46ed-b51d-e6fde35b5b76' for list template '100' is not installed in this farm.  The operation could not be completed.`.

With powershell, you can then find the troubled list `$web.lists | ? TemplateFeatureId -eq "102e3c2b-02a2-46ed-b51d-e6fde35b5b76"`. And you may choose to call `.Delete()` on the list object if appripriate. Or perhaps import solution that has that particular template id. 

I know it's no use to you after 8 years, but I did have to deal with it in 2021 :)

Answer (score 0):

Garrisons solution is not a solution to the problem. The problem is caused by a broken list like in the site mentioned earlier. See here: http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-designer-2010-listlibrary-there-are-no-items-to-show-in-this-view-listdata-svc-woes

The solution is removing the list that is broken using powershell. That should make the lists reappear and _vti_bin/listdata.svc work again.

Comment: Okay, but how do I find the broken list?  Myself, I can't navigate to `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc` - it asks me over and over to authenticate and never lets me in, even though I'm farm admin.

Answer (score 0):

i was have the same problem and the solution is there is list is broken but unfortunately you can detect this list so following the steps

1- backup your site with power shell or stsadm command

2- try to delete list by list and after delete one test the SPD it will find the that broken

3- restore the site and delete just the broken list

4- don't be afraid when you delete lists take your backup first and the restore is very easy

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem which I discovered was caused by a list previously deployed by a sandboxed solution which was retracted. The broken list showed up in Site Contents, but when trying to access it, the "Something went wrong" error showed.
Solved by manually deleting the problematic list from Site Contents (user UI)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very useful, and I have a slight optimisation to the discovery of broken lists.
My client had done a DB migration from 2007 to 2010 and we're moving them to SPO now, so this is a blocker. Many of the lists they have that are broken are derived from either Fab40 templates or the Group Work feature.
SharePoint Manager 2010 can show you the affected lists faster than Preview in SPD.
The first trick is to find out in which Webs the List Data service is broken. Using PowerShell, spit out the URLs of all webs in all SPSites, something like:

```
get-spsite -limit all | get-spweb -limit all | select URL | export-csv -notypeinformation -path c:\Borked\Webs.csv
```

Then open that in Excel, save as an XLSX. 
In column B tack on the Vti bin path
=concat(A2,"/_vti_bin/ListData.svc")

Then, if the list of webs is small, you can open them in the browser to check for broken webs, if it's larger, you could pass them into an invoke-webRequest cmdlet.

Navigate to the affected web(s), in our case it's 8 of 90 or so, in SharePoint Manager.
Browse to 'Lists' and click each list in turn. You can get through them pretty quickly. The faulty ones will throw an error dialog, but more usefully, they'll also show it to you for retrieval. I added the error to the spreadsheet for stripping out later.
This will help you hunt down the features that caused the problem in the first place. FeatureAdmin or if you're brave/stupid, stsadm -o deactivatefeature and -o uninstallfeature

Or, a neater way, thanks to [How to remove orphaned features](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16525/how-to-remove-orphaned-features/81305)

```
Get-SPFeature | ? { !$_.Scope } | % { $_.Delete() }
```

[image: Corrupted list in SPM]

[image: semi-deleted list in SPM]

Answer (score -1):

Check the "SharePoint Designer Settings" at site collection and webapplication level

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did check the SharePoint Designer settings. All permissions are selected globally and for the site collection in question. The top level site in the collection is working correctly; Only the subsite has issues.