# Why isn't SharePoint Designer 2010 showing anything under "List and Libraries"?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

SharePoint Designer 2010 is not showing anything under "List and Libraries" on one of my site collections even though I see all list and libraries in another SharePoint 2010 site. The "Data Sources" heading also does not show any items in SharePoint Designer. Also when I try to browse ListData.svc service by following address:

http://rootsitecollection/_vti_bin/listdata.svc

then the browser cannot browse the XML file. "ListData.svc" is present and working correctly on another SharePoint site. User permission is correctly assigned on the web application and site collection level.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have any custom list or custom document libraries been created? If you look at the view all site content http://rootsitecollection/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx page do you see any duplicate lists or document libraries?

Answer (score 3):

Please read the following article.

http://decoiled.com/post/2012/05/15/SharePoint-Designer-2010-does-not-show-Lists-and-Libraries.aspx

I attempted to write the following comment for that article, but their website wasn't accepting comments for some reason:

You can test the underlying web service that SPDesigner uses to lists these lists by appending "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc" to the site URL. You should find that on sites where SP Designer's list of lists works, this URL will return XML. On sites where SP Designer's list of lists doesn't work, you will get an extremely non-descript error.

In some instances you can still see the lists in "**View All Site Content**". If you **click each individual list**, you may find that *manually enumerating through these lists may produce a useful error message*. If you don't need that list, you can use the 'delete corrupted list using stsadm' command to delete the corrupt list if the list is not important:

```
stsadm –o forcedeletelist –url http://sharepointserver/lists/yourcorruptedlist
```

However, If you need to recover the data on that list, take a look at the correlation you receive from the attempt to view the list, and attempt to solve that problem - you may find a feature is disabled or something... Worst case scenario I expect you can recover the data from the database somewhere (maybe via SSRS?).*

For me, I found that the problems were caused by empty, unimportant lists. When I was able to successfully "manually enumerate" through that list of lists, then the underlying web service started working, and after closing and re-opening SP Designer, Designer started working too.

* Disclaimer: modifying SP or even viewing databases directly may leave your farm in an unsupported state. At this point I would recommend contacting Microsoft.

Comment: I have a problem on my root site, where SPD won't display things in the "Site Objects" objects - you know, "Site Pages", "Lists and Libraries", etc. over in the left Navigation (in SPD).  The Subsites work fine, though.  How can I find the broken list?

Comment: I've clicked on every item in "All Site Content" and they all work; but SPD doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem, I found a way.

First, I knew a list was broken, based on symptoms reported from other answers in this very post ([and this one, too](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12191/why-dont-lists-and-libraries-show-up-in-sharepoint-designer?rq=1)).  For one, alirobe's mentioning that `/_vti_bin/ListData.svc` isn't accessible if a list is broken.

When I went to "All Site Content", every list given there *did* work.

I couldn't discover which list it was that was broken, so in SPD, I went to "All Files" in Sharepoint Designer - which worked, even though many of the other Site Objects in "Navigation" didn't display anything.

I went through every list in "All Files" and used "Preview in Browser" on every one of them.  Finally, I came to one that didn't open!  Instead, it said,

> feature d57f48.... for list template '100' is not installed in this farm...

So I deleted that list and everything began working again just fine in SPD.

Comment: Do you remember the name of the list?

Comment: @theMayer it was just a custom list that I had made - nothing irregular - and had saved as a list template

Comment: thank you! :) you saved me couple of hours and frustration! :)

Answer (score 0):

On the first issue, this seems to usually occur when upgrading from SharePoint 2007. Here are some things you can try:

- Check that the site collection administrators are set correctly
- Recreate the top level site collection
- Check that any features required by custom list templates are installed

Further reading [here](http://spgeekchick.com/2011/02/13/sharepoint-designer-2010-error-list-and-libraries-no-items-to-display/) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/bc0c2470-4837-4b5b-b1e8-075312f11093).

Not sure about the second issue - it is probably related. Please ask a new question if not.