# Can't create list workflow in SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow

I would like to create a list workflow in SharePoint Designer. When I choose the custom list, I want to assign the new workflow but nothing happens (The window does not appear and I don't get any error or anything). I can create reuseable and site workflows, but not list workflows.

Also there are 2 existing and working list workflows which were added to the site before migrating from the developer server to the production server. I can still add list workflows to my developer server, but I can't on the production server.

So I suspect migration issue (but not sure). Do you have any idea what could be wrong or what should I check to restrict the possible reasons?

UPDATE: Looks like I can't see any list in the Sharepoint Designer however they exist and works well on the site.

Comment: This solved the problem:   https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12191/why-dont-lists-and-libraries-show-up-in-sharepoint-designer